# Зависает Visual Studio 2015 после выхода из QtDesigner

Tags: visual-studio

Редактирую окна в Qt Designer, потом нажимаю "выход", чтобы вернуться обратно в студию, дизайнер закрывается, но окно студии остается зависнутым, при этом оно не помечается, как окно, которое зависло ("не отвечает").
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Опишите более подробно: что редактируете? Что в этот момент открыто в VS? Что подразумевается под состоянием зависнутое VS?

Comment: @NMD Редактирую ,например, слоты кнопок. После чего нажимаю "сохранить" (это важно, если ничего не менять, то всё ОК). После нажимаю "выход" (чтобы вернуться непосредственно к коду. Окно QtDesigner закрывается, а окно студии (целиком) становится неактивно (ни на что не реагирует). В диспетчере задач в этот момент студия занимает 1.2 гб оперативной памяти и 40% нагрузки на ЦП. Ожидал в течении 5-7 минут, окно не отвисало. Закрывается через завершение процесса devenv.exe и то не сразу.

Comment: @NMD открыты: solution explorer и собственно одно окно с кодом

Comment: @NMD QtDesigner открываю через студию. Путем открытия .ui

Comment: Для ассоциации QtDesigner с .ui в VS делали какие-то настройки или устанавливали плагин?

Comment: @NMD просто установил Qt для MSVS2015. Я нашёл решение (плохое, но работает), если в настройках выставить открытие окна Qt Designer в отдельном окне (а не в окне VS), то при его закрытии ничего не зависает.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующее решение:
Qt VS Tools -> Options -> Qt -> General -> Qt Designer -> True
[image]